# Does the well ordering principle really implies mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Under the Peano Axioms, I want to prove that if the Axiom of Induction is substituted with the well-ordering principle (every non-empty subset of $
\mathbb N$ has a minimum element), everything will be fine. That means I should prove that they are equivalent, as the proof can be found in various textbooks. However, I found a problem when proving that the well-ordering principle implies mathematical induction. The proof follows:

> Let $P(0)$ be true and $P(n)\implies P(n^+)$. Suppose $A=\{x\in\mathbb N:P(x)\text{ is false.}\}$ is non-empty, then let $m$ be its least element. Since $P(0)$ is true, $m\neq 0$. **Therefore, there must be some $n$ such that $m=n^+$**. By definition of $m$, $P(n)$ is true, but this implies $P(n^+)=P(m)$ is true, a contradiction.

The statement in bold seems to be correct, but the Peano Axioms do not include it (every natural number is either 0 or a successor of a natural number). In fact, it's usually proven via mathematical induction, which we cannot use in the proof above.

Question: How can this flaw be fixed, or they (AI and WOP) are simply not equivalent?

**Note:** I found a paper claiming that they are not equivalent and most textbooks get it wrong. But I haven't read it. Link: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-019-09898-4

Comment: The paper that you found shows that the statement in bold does not in fact follow from the Peano axioms without the induction axiom. It does follow if one replaces the axiom that says that $0$ is not a successor with an axiom saying that $0$ is the **unique** natural number that is not a successor.